# Custom control didn't set bg radius from css

Tags: javafx

I've been created my first custom skinable control. The color set by css works fine, but when I'm trying to set radius for background or border it didn't works. How to modify these classes to do they works with other dimentions CSS properties ?  All tutorials that I found explain only how to set a new color css property. Could you link me other examples ?

Control Class

```
public class HeaderPane extends Control {

    private static final String DEFAULT_CLASS_NAME = "header-pane";
    private static final String BACKGROUND_CSS_PROPERTY = "-fx-header-background-color";
    private static final Color DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.web("#0188AE");

    private final SimpleStringProperty title = new SimpleStringProperty("Header Title");

    private ObjectProperty<Color>   backgroundColor = new StyleableObjectProperty<Color>(DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR) {
(..)
    };


    private final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>> onAction = new ObjectPropertyBase<EventHandler<ActionEvent>>() {
       (...)

    };
    public HeaderPane() {
        initialize();
       // createDefaultSkin();
        updateBackgroundColor();
    }

    public HeaderPane(String title) {
        this.title.set(title);
        initialize();
        createDefaultSkin();
        updateBackgroundColor();

    }

    private void initialize() {
        getStyleClass().add(DEFAULT_CLASS_NAME);
    }

    void updateBackgroundColor() {
        setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(getBackgroundColor(), null, Insets.EMPTY)));
    }

//     GETTERS SETTERS
 (...)

 // .    Inner static class Styleable properties
    private static class StyleableProperties {
        private static final CssMetaData<HeaderPane, Color> STYLEABLES = . (...)
    /**
     * Create DefaultSkin override
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new HeaderPaneSkin(this);
    }

    // * Return default Css
    @Override
    public String getUserAgentStylesheet() { (...) }
}
```

Skin Class

```
public class HeaderPaneSkin extends SkinBase<HeaderPane> {
    private final Color default_color = Color.web("#0188AE");

    @Getter
    private final AnchorPane backgroundPane;
    private final Label title;
    private boolean invalidate = false;
    private final InvalidationListener invalidListener = observable -> invalidate = true;

    {
        backgroundPane = new AnchorPane();
        title = new Label();
    }

    public HeaderPaneSkin(HeaderPane control) {
        super(control);
        initialize();

        getSkinnable().prefWidthProperty().bind(backgroundPane.widthProperty());
        getSkinnable().prefHeightProperty().bind(backgroundPane.heightProperty());

        getSkinnable().widthProperty().addListener(invalidListener);
        getSkinnable().heightProperty().addListener(invalidListener);

        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(title, 20.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(title, 20.0);

    }

    private void initialize() {
        getChildren().add(backgroundPane);
        backgroundPane.getChildren().addAll(title);
        title.textProperty().bind(getSkinnable().titleProperty());
    }
}
```

@fabian

```
 @Override
protected List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> getControlCssMetaData() {
    return getClassCssMetaData();
}

public static List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> getClassCssMetaData() {
    return StyleableProperties.cssMetaDataList;
}
```

Comment: I do not see an override of the [`getCssMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getCssMetaData--) method. Furthermore you should avoid using double-`{` initialisation, since for every element you initialize this way, another `.class` file is created... Better initialize it a initializer/the constructors.

Comment: this is under " Inner static class Styleable properties" . I must remove them from copied code because there is more code than text...  For the initialize I dont understand what exactly you mean